# How to init file object in a java web application with the correct path

Tags: java, netbeans, web-applications, primefaces

[image]

So this is the folder structure of my web app. I am going to have some images uploaded here frequently which will be placed in ***images*** folder. Now what I am trying to do is to get a list of available images in a sub-foler of ***images*** folder. I am using the following code (located in BtsEvent.java and called from table.xhtml):

```
    List<String> lstFileNames =  new ArrayList<String>();
    // read all image files from folder

    File folder = new File("images/EventID1/");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
```

and I get java.lang.NullPointerException exception. I think another method for getting file paths is required. How can I correctly init folder object?

Comment: I think the path that you use is incorrect did you try another path ?!? (try somthing from the root like this one `/root/file/...`)

Comment: Other paths are also not working.